# Unexpected characters injected when copying from clipboard to vim in terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, iterm2

I'm using OS X 10.14/Vim 8.0.1283 and iTerm2. Every time when I'm copying things from clipboard to terminal, in specific iTerm2, there will be some unexpected characters injected in. 
Say I'm copying `Explore Our Questions` from clipboard to terminal, it ends up being `[200~Explore Our Questions[201~]]`. 
I'm very confused about where are these `[200~` and `[201~]]` from. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

Comment: IMO that's the "bracketed paste mode" in terminals. I know in Linux we can disable that by adding a few lines to shell rc. But I have no idea about mac.

Comment: `:set t_BE=` (see `:h xterm-bracketed-paste`)

Comment: vim help really does have everything in it